# Dynamic Bar Graph Using AchartEngine Library

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, android-graphview

[image]

In The Above Screen Shot You Can See the First  Bar  and its corresponding value is cutting from left.I want To put some Margin from left so the first bar will fit in the screen along with its value. I have tried a lot but not able to do that.Please someone help me  if you can. thnks.

Following are the set of code Which i have written to achieve this.

```
  CalorieConsumedTrackerActivity.java

  public class CalorieConsumedTrackerActivity extends Activity {

private GraphicalView mChart;
JSONArray dailydata = null;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static String url_display_user ;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "getdata";
JSONArray graphdatas = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getdata;
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
String userid=null;
String[] mMonth = new String[7] ;
String[] datefromdb = new String[7] ;

int[] line = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] target = new int[7];
int[] consumed = new int[7];

int[]showtarget=new int[7];
int[]showconsumed=new int[7];



XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Target");
// Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Consumed");
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calories_consumed ); 

    getdata=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    user=db.getUserDetails();
    userid=user.get("userid");

    TextView lstweek=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lstweek);
    lstweek.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));

    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    myCalendar.set(myCalendar.getTime().getYear()+1900,myCalendar.getTime().getMonth() , myCalendar.getTime().getDate());
    for (int i = 6; i >=0; i--) {
        myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()); 
        System.out.println(date);
        mMonth[i]=date;


    }


    new GetGraphData().execute();
}

private void openChart(){

}   

class GetGraphData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CalorieConsumedTrackerActivity.this, "wait", "Fetching...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        url_display_user = "http://www.bharatwellness.com/getGraphData.php";

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_display_user,
                "GET", parametres);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All data : ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            JSONObject c=null;

            if (success == 1) {
                int i;
                int cal=0;
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                graphdatas = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

                // looping through All RESPONSE
                for (i = 0; i < graphdatas.length(); i++) {

                    c = graphdatas.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable

                    String createddate = c.getString("createddate");
                    datefromdb[i]=createddate;
                    String caloriegoal = c.getString("caloriegoal");
                    String calorieconsumed = c.getString("calorieconsumed");
                    double cgoal=Double.parseDouble(caloriegoal);
                    cal=(int) Math.round(cgoal);
                    target[i]=cal;
                    double csumed=Double.parseDouble(calorieconsumed);
                    int calc=(int) Math.round(csumed);
                    consumed[i]=calc;

                }


                for(int x=0;x<mMonth.length;x++){

                    for(int y=0;y<datefromdb.length;y++){

                        if(mMonth[x].equals(datefromdb[y])){

                            showconsumed[x]=consumed[y];
                            showtarget[x]=target[y];


                        }
                        if(showtarget[x]==0){

                            showtarget[x]=cal;
                        }


                    }

                }
                // Creating an  XYSeries for Income

                // Adding data to Income and Expense Series



                for(int j=0;j<line.length;j++){


                    incomeSeries.add(line[j], showtarget[j]);
                    expenseSeries.add(line[j],showconsumed[j]);


                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
                        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
                        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
                        // Adding Expense Series to dataset
                        dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);       


                        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
                        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#04B431"));
                        incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
                        incomeRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(20);
                        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(27);
                        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

                        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
                        XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                        expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
                        expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                        expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                        expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                        expenseRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(27);
                        expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


                        for(int z=0;z<mMonth.length;z++){
                            String createddate=mMonth[z];
                            String month=createddate.substring(5, 7);
                            System.out.println(month);
                            int m=Integer.parseInt(month);
                            System.out.println(m);
                            switch (m) {
                            case 1:
                                month="Jan";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                month="Feb";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                month="Mar";
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                month="Apr";
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                month="May";
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                month="June";
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                month="July";
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                month="Aug";
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                month="Sep";
                                break;
                            case 10:
                                month="Oct";
                                break;
                            case 11:
                                month="Nov";
                                break;

                            case 12:
                                month="Dec";
                                break;
                            }

                            String day=createddate.substring(8, 10);

                            String finaldate= day+" "+month;



                            mMonth[z]=finaldate ;
                        }


                        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
                        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
                        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
                        multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
                        multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
                        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
                        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Calories Consumed Progress Chart");
                        multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);

                        multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                        multiRenderer.setXTitle("");
                        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Calories");

                        //  multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
                        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
                        multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
                        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(24);
                        multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);

                        multiRenderer.setXRoundedLabels(true);
                        multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
                        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(3000);


                        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
                        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
                        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
                        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 30, 30,20, 0 });
                        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
                        multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);

                        for(int i=0;i<mMonth.length;i++){

                            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mMonth[i]);

                        }       

                        // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
                        // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
                        // should be same
                        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
                        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);
                        multiRenderer.setYLabels(6);
                        //multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);

                        // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
                        LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
                        chartContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                        chartContainer.setScrollContainer(true);


                        LinearLayout con = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
                        con.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);





                        // Specifying chart types to be drawn in the graph
                        // Number of data series and number of types should be same
                        // Order of data series and chart type will be same
                        String[] types = new String[] { LineChart.TYPE, BarChart.TYPE };

                        // Creating a combined chart with the chart types specified in types array
                        mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);
                        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
                        multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

                        multiRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(30.0f);
                        multiRenderer.setYLabelsAngle(30.0f);
                        multiRenderer.setBarWidth(10);

                        multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);

                        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(7.5);
                        multiRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
                        multiRenderer.setFitLegend(false);
                        multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(19);

                        multiRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
                        // Adding the Combined Chart to the LinearLayout
                        chartContainer.addView(mChart);  
                    }});


                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products



        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread


        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: how about adding a bar with empty title and zero value before your first bar?

Comment: @KomaYip Can u modify the same code  please...